# Excel duplicates based on diff column

Tags: excel

Good morning. 
Lets say I have this data.

on column A (Dates) how I keep only the latest value for duplicates in B column(member), but if its unique value keep it too.

[image: orig]

This is the result I want.

[image: result]

Comment: Sort by the data first priority B ascending then A descending.  Then use Remove duplicates on Column B

Comment: You solved to questions at the same time, thank you. !!